# How to get HTML5 and Maxmind gelocation features working with varnish?

Tags: html, nginx, geolocation, varnish

I recently installed varnish on my servers in order to ease the workload a bit. However one of my websites extensively uses the HTML5 'navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()' function and also falls back on the maxmind database installed into nginx when the aforementioned is not available.

I can understand why the nginx/maxmind version won't work as it relies on the nginx server knowing what IP you are from, and as varnish is sitting in front, requests may not even get as far as nginx.

However, why is the HTML5 geolocation function not working? I assumed this was purely client side and should be unaffected by the web server?

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the Nginx Http GeoIP module working behind a proxy, you will need to pass the IP address of your proxy server to the [geoip_proxy directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_geoip_module.html#geoip_proxy).

I don't know if we have enough information to speculate about why the W3C Geolocation function is not working. As you suggest, there is no obvious reason why it should not work when your site is behind a proxy server.

As an aside, you might want to check out [MaxMind's GeoIP2 JavaScript service](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/javascript/), which tries to use W3C Geolocation and then falls back on the web service if that is not available. MaxMind provides a free option that might meet your needs.